# How can I add a column with the count of rows if the date is between two dates

Tags: r, excel

I am used to working in Excel. I have a question regarding adding a new column with the counts of rows that are between two dates.

For example:

```
week  start_date    end_date
1     2019-05-01    2019-05-07
2     2019-05-08    2019-05-14
```

Another data set has different rows with dates:

```
Date           Response
2019-05-01     AC
2019-05-01     AC
2019-05-03     AC
2019-05-05     AC
2019-05-06     AC
2019-05-06     AC
2019-05-07     AC
2019-05-08     AC
2019-05-09     AC
2019-05-10     AC
2019-05-11     AC
2019-05-11     AC
2019-05-11     AC
```

I would like to add a column in the first with the number of new contacts per week.

In Excel would be something like this:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!B:B (Date) ,">="& Sheet2!B2 (Start_date), Sheet1!B:B (Date), "<=" & Sheet2!C2 (enddate) 

week  start_date end_date    number
1   2019-05-01  2019-05-07   7
2   2019-05-08  2019-05-14   6
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hi @AlejandraCardenas  please let me know if my answer helped. If yes, please mark it with the checkmark. If not let me know and I’ll try to help.

Answer (score 0):

You would add the dates to a vector (as dates if you like) and then call for the length of the vector with the right conditions.

```
dates <- as.Date(c("2019-05-01 AC", "2019-05-01 AC", "2019-05-03 AC", "2019-05-05 AC", "2019-05-06 AC", "2019-05-06 AC", "2019-05-07 AC", "2019-05-08 AC", "2019-05-09 AC", "2019-05-10 AC", "2019-05-11 AC", "2019-05-11 AC", "2019-05-11 AC"))

length(dates[dates>="2019-05-01" & dates<="2019-05-07"])
```

The implementation for how to do this by making a new column with the data pairs is dependent on what form that data is in. I presume you will be able to sort it out from here.